# Comodo internet security detect c++ hello world program as a viruses (trojan)

Tags: c++, warnings, virus, trojan

I am using **dev c++ 4.9.9.2** editor for running my code.

Comodo internet security detect c++ hello world program as a virus.

The program is shown below -

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
return 0;
}
```

Comodo internet security detect the c++ file as a -

**TrojWare.Win32.Trojen.Killfiles.aml0@105409181**

Comment: Some antivirus software has a propensity to "false positive" detection.

Comment: Thanks . What is the solution for bypass the false alert?

Comment: Typically, use a differnt antivirus software...

Comment: It could also be that your computer is infected with something and is infecting the executables you create. In any case I don't think this is really a question for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem. Since I know there is no virus in the programs, I excluded my dev c++ folder and program file folders from antivirus software.

Steps in comodo antivirus is:

1.Open **CIS**

2.click **Tasks** in upper right corner

3.click **Advanced tasks**

4.select **open advanced settings**

5.Expand **security settings**

6.Expand **antivirus**

7.click **Exclusions**

8.Click on the arrow or right click anywhere on the screen.

9.select **Add->folders**

10.Add the dev c++ folders and program files folder in the list.

11.You have excluded the files

Now run your program, will surely get the output without any virus.